# What is the most efficient upgrade path?

Tags: vampire-survivors

In Vampire Survivors, I've been mostly focusing on the Greed upgrade to help speed up my overall ability to upgrade by getting more coins, and then upgrading other things (extra damage/attacks/cooldown/etc). Considering that upgrading something will increase the cost of other related upgrades, as well as the ability to refund all upgrades at 100% cost, what is the most efficient way to buy every upgrade for the least amount of coins given that I have all upgrades unlocked?

Comment: Link-only answers aren't allowed, so here. There's a calculator: https://benediktwerner.github.io/vampire-survivors-power-up-calculator/ There's a ton of useful resources pinned in the official Discord's #spoiler channel.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is by always upgrading the most expensive item first.

I was googling the same question and there were suggested paths but they didn't make sense + the game is being updated every week and there are few items that might not be worth throwing so much coin at (reroll and skip)

1. Go through all the items
2. See which upgrade is the most expensive
3. Buy that
4. Go back to step 1. until you have everything upgraded

Every time you buy an upgrade all the remaining upgrades become more expensive thus going for the priciest items first is the best strategy.

That all goes out of the window if you can't afford all the upgrades (100k+)
If that is the case then buy upgrades based on your style, you can later re-set for a full refund and buy differently.

Comment: So, cheapest or most expensive? Your first sentence says "cheapest first", but the algorithm you list has "expensive first".

Comment: @JanDorniak oops, good catch. Most-expensive always